# Using SleepEx and ReadFileEx functions for asynchronous reading from a serial port. SleepEx function doesn't work for the ReadFileEx function

Tags: c++, asynchronous, winapi, serial-port

My problem started with that I read that the `SleepEx( )` function can be used with asynchronous functions and I decided to try it, but I can't do what I want all day.
I have experience with using the serial port. I have working programs, both with the use of synchronous functions, and with asynchronous, with the use of events.
What I want:
I want to read through `ReadFileEx( )` function without using the standard `Sleep( )` function and without events, as it must remain blocked until it reads some data and then I receive the data immediately.
What is happening:
The `ReadFileEx( )` function returns instantly, which is good, but apparently the `SleepEx( )` function doesn't work, because it also returns instantly, which leads to thousands of calls to `ReadFileEx( )` function, as you can see from the print in the console:

```
             Normal Serial Communication

Send :       26    Write:   0.02ms (  0.02 /   0.02)
Read :       26     Read:   0.00ms (  0.00 /   0.00)    Called: 4

Send :    27 F6    Write:   0.02ms (  0.02 /   0.02)
Read :    27 F6     Read:   0.00ms (  0.00 /   0.01)    Called: 5

Send : 85 97 15    Write:   0.02ms (  0.02 /   0.02)
Read : 85 97 15     Read:   0.00ms (  0.00 /   0.01)    Called: 5

         Overlapped Serial Communication

Send :       26    Write:   0.02ms (  0.01 /   0.02)
                   Sleep:   0.02ms (  0.02 /   0.02)
Read :       26     Read:   0.00ms (  0.00 /   0.01)    Called: 1041
                   Sleep:   0.00ms (  0.00 /   0.00)

Send :    27 F6    Write:   0.02ms (  0.01 /   0.02)
                   Sleep:   0.02ms (  0.02 /   0.02)
Read :    27 F6     Read:   0.00ms (  0.00 /   0.15)    Called: 1214
                   Sleep:   0.00ms (  0.00 /   0.03)

Send : 85 97 15    Write:   0.01ms (  0.01 /   0.02)
                   Sleep:   0.02ms (  0.02 /   0.02)
Read : 85 97 15     Read:   0.00ms (  0.00 /   0.15)    Called: 1467
                   Sleep:   0.00ms (  0.00 /   0.03)
```

This leads to high CPU usage.
I wrote a test example, but you don't need to look at the whole code, just pay attention to the `cSerial::readAsync( )` and the `cSerial::writeAsync( )`. Everything else is standard and helps to show the execution times of the functions.
I used a develpment female cable to connect the TX pin to the RX pin of my DB9 male connector on the computer, so I made "Serial Loopback".
The program is console application and was compiled and tested with Visualstudio 2005.:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <tchar.h>

#define MAX_BYTES_SND_RCV 3

// Debug Timer Class
class cHighResTimer {
    private:
        LARGE_INTEGER frequency, start_tmr;
        double min = 1E+10, max = 0, avg = 0, num = 0;
        TCHAR timer_name[ 8 ];
    public:
        void Start( void ) { ::QueryPerformanceCounter( &start_tmr ); }
        void Stop( void ) {
            LARGE_INTEGER stop_tmr;
            ::QueryPerformanceCounter( &stop_tmr );
            double time_us = (stop_tmr.QuadPart - start_tmr.QuadPart) * 1E+3 / frequency.QuadPart;
            if( time_us < min ) min = time_us;
            if( time_us > max ) max = time_us;
            avg += time_us;
            num++;
        }
        void Print( void ) {
            _tprintf( _T("%*s: %6.2fms (%6.2f / %6.2f)"), ( int )_countof( timer_name ), timer_name, avg/num, min, max );
        }
        cHighResTimer( LPCTSTR name ) {
            _tcscpy_s( timer_name, name );
            ::QueryPerformanceFrequency( &frequency );
        }
};

void PrintHEX( LPCTSTR prefix, const void* data, size_t data_size ) {
    const uint8_t* dta = ( const uint8_t* )data;
    _tprintf( _T("%s"), prefix );
    if( MAX_BYTES_SND_RCV > data_size )
    for( size_t i = 0; i < MAX_BYTES_SND_RCV - data_size; i++ ) _tprintf( _T("   ")  );
    for( size_t i = 0; i < data_size; i++ ) _tprintf( _T("%02X "), ( unsigned int )dta[ i ] );
}

class cSerial {
    private:
        HANDLE hPort = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
        cHighResTimer tmrRead,  tmrSleepRead;   // Debug Help Timers for Read
        cHighResTimer tmrWrite, tmrSleepWrite;  // Debug Help Timers for Write
        DWORD flags;
        static VOID WINAPI cbCompletion( DWORD dwErrorCode, DWORD dwNumberOfBytesTransfered, LPOVERLAPPED lpOverlapped ) {
            DWORD& bytes_transfered = *( DWORD* )&lpOverlapped->hEvent;
            bytes_transfered = ( !dwErrorCode ) ? dwNumberOfBytesTransfered : -1;
        }
        LPCTSTR strRead = _T("Read : ");
        LPCTSTR strSend = _T("Send : ");
        // Syncronious Read
        size_t readsync( void *buf, size_t nbytes ) {
            DWORD time_out_timer = GetTickCount( );
            DWORD NumberOfBytesRead;
            DWORD total_readed = 0;
            DWORD n_call_func = 0;
            BOOL rf_rv;
            do {
                n_call_func++;
                tmrRead.Start( );
                rf_rv = ReadFile( hPort, ( uint8_t* )buf + total_readed, ( DWORD )nbytes - total_readed, &NumberOfBytesRead, NULL );
                tmrRead.Stop( );
                if( rf_rv ) {
                    if( ( total_readed += NumberOfBytesRead ) >= nbytes ) break;
                    Sleep( 1 );
                }
                if( GetTickCount( ) - time_out_timer >= 50 ) rf_rv = false; // Time out expired
            } while( rf_rv );
            PrintHEX( strRead, buf, total_readed );
            tmrRead.Print( );
            _tprintf( _T("\tCalled: %u\r\n"), n_call_func );
            return rf_rv ? total_readed : -1;
        }
        // Syncronious Write
        size_t writesync( const void *buf, size_t nbytes ) {
            DWORD NumberOfBytesWritten;
            BOOL wf_rv;
            tmrWrite.Start( );
            wf_rv = WriteFile( hPort, buf, ( DWORD )nbytes, &NumberOfBytesWritten, NULL );
            tmrWrite.Stop( );
            PrintHEX( strSend, buf, NumberOfBytesWritten );
            tmrWrite.Print( );
            _tprintf( _T("\r\n") );
            return wf_rv ? NumberOfBytesWritten : -1;
        }
        // Asyncronious Read
        size_t readAsync( void *buf, size_t nbytes ) {
            OVERLAPPED osReader = { 0 };
            DWORD& bytes_transfered = *( DWORD* )&osReader.hEvent;
            DWORD err = ERROR_SUCCESS;
            LPCTSTR err_name = NULL;
            DWORD sl_rv = -1;
            DWORD time_out_timer = GetTickCount( );
            DWORD total_readed = 0;
            DWORD n_call_func = 0;
            BOOL rd_fl;

            do {
                n_call_func++;
                tmrRead.Start( );
                rd_fl = ReadFileEx( hPort, ( uint8_t* )buf + total_readed, ( DWORD )nbytes - total_readed, &osReader, ( LPOVERLAPPED_COMPLETION_ROUTINE )cbCompletion );
                tmrRead.Stop( );
                if( rd_fl ) {
                    if( (err = GetLastError( )) == ERROR_SUCCESS ) {
                        tmrSleepRead.Start( );
                        sl_rv = SleepEx( 100, TRUE );
                        tmrSleepRead.Stop( );
                        if( sl_rv == WAIT_IO_COMPLETION ) {
                            if( bytes_transfered >= 1 ) {
                                if( ( total_readed += bytes_transfered ) == nbytes ) break;
                            } else if( !bytes_transfered ) {
                                // Why I am here ?
                            } else {
                                err_name = _T("Error in Completion cb function!");
                                break;
                            }
                        } else {
                            err_name = _T("Time out!");
                        }
                    } else {
                        break;
                    }
                } else {
                    err = GetLastError( );
                }
                if( GetTickCount( ) - time_out_timer >= 50 ) rd_fl = false; // Time out expired
            } while( rd_fl );

            if( total_readed == nbytes ) {
                PrintHEX( strRead, buf, nbytes );
            } else {
                _tprintf( _T("%*s"), ( int )_tcslen( strRead ) + MAX_BYTES_SND_RCV * 3, _T(" ") );
            }
            tmrRead.Print( );
            _tprintf( _T("\tCalled: %u\r\n"), n_call_func );

            if( sl_rv != -1 ) {
                _tprintf( _T("%*s"), ( int )_tcslen( strRead ) + MAX_BYTES_SND_RCV * 3, _T(" ") );
                tmrSleepRead.Print( );
                _tprintf( _T("\r\n") );
            }
            if( err != ERROR_SUCCESS ) _tprintf( _T("Write Error: %u\r\n"), err );
            if( err_name != NULL ) _tprintf( _T("Write Error: %s\r\n"), err_name );

            return (rd_fl && ( total_readed == nbytes )) ? total_readed : -1;
        }
        // Asyncronious Write
        size_t writeAsync( const void *buf, size_t nbytes ) {
            OVERLAPPED osWriter = { 0 };
            DWORD& bytes_transfered = *( DWORD* )&osWriter.hEvent;
            BOOL wr_fl;
            DWORD err;
            LPCTSTR err_name = NULL;
            DWORD sl_rv = -1;
            size_t rv = -1;

            tmrWrite.Start( );
            wr_fl = WriteFileEx( hPort, buf, ( DWORD )nbytes, &osWriter, ( LPOVERLAPPED_COMPLETION_ROUTINE )cbCompletion );
            tmrWrite.Stop( );

            if( wr_fl ) {
                if( (err = GetLastError( )) == ERROR_SUCCESS ) {
                    tmrSleepWrite.Start( );
                    sl_rv = SleepEx( INFINITE, TRUE );
                    tmrSleepWrite.Stop( );
                    if( sl_rv == WAIT_IO_COMPLETION ) {
                        if( bytes_transfered == nbytes ) {
                            rv = bytes_transfered;
                        } else {
                            err_name = _T("Not all bytes are sent!");
                        }
                    } else {
                        err_name = _T("Time out!");
                    }
                }
            } else {
                err = GetLastError( );
            }

            PrintHEX( strSend, buf, nbytes );
            tmrWrite.Print( );
            _tprintf( _T("\r\n") );
            if( sl_rv != -1 ) {
                _tprintf( _T("%*s"), ( int )_tcslen( strSend ) + MAX_BYTES_SND_RCV * 3, _T(" ") );
                tmrSleepWrite.Print( );
                _tprintf( _T("\r\n") );
            }
            if( rv == -1 ) {
                if( err != ERROR_SUCCESS ) _tprintf( _T("Write Error: %u\r\n"), err );
                else if( err_name != NULL ) _tprintf( _T("Write Error: %s\r\n"), err_name );
            }
            return rv;
        }
    public:
        size_t read( void *buf, size_t nbytes ) {
            return (flags & FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED) ? readAsync( buf, nbytes ) : readsync( buf, nbytes );
        }
        size_t write( const void *buf, size_t nbytes ) {
            return (flags & FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED) ? writeAsync( buf, nbytes ) : writesync( buf, nbytes );
        }
        BOOL InitSerial( LPCTSTR serial_port, DWORD baud_rate, DWORD flags ) {
            TCHAR dn_port[ 16 ];
            DCB PortDCB;
            bool rv = false;

            // Save flags
            this->flags = flags;

            // Open Serial Port
            _stprintf_s( dn_port, _T("\\\\.\\%s"), serial_port );
            hPort = CreateFile ( dn_port, GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, flags, NULL );
            if( hPort == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE ) goto _exit;

            // Configure COM port
            GetCommState( hPort, &PortDCB );
            PortDCB.BaudRate = baud_rate;
            PortDCB.ByteSize = 8;
            PortDCB.Parity = NOPARITY;
            PortDCB.StopBits = ONESTOPBIT;
            if( !SetCommState( hPort, &PortDCB ) ) goto _exit;
            rv = true;
        _exit:
            if( (!rv) && (hPort != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) ) {
                CloseHandle( hPort );
                hPort = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
            }
            return rv;
        }
        void CloseSerial( void ) {
            if( hPort != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE ) {
                CloseHandle( hPort );
                hPort = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
            }
        }
        cSerial( ) :
            tmrRead ( _T("Read"  ) ), tmrSleepRead ( _T("Sleep" ) ),
            tmrWrite( _T("Write" ) ), tmrSleepWrite( _T("Sleep" ) ) { }
        ~cSerial( ) { CloseSerial( ); }
};

void main( int argc, char** argv ) {
    cSerial Serial;
    uint8_t snd_bff[ MAX_BYTES_SND_RCV ], rcv_bff[ MAX_BYTES_SND_RCV ];
    LPCTSTR serial_port = (argc >= 2) ? argv[ 1 ] : NULL;

    if( serial_port != NULL ) {
        auto SerialTest =
            [ &Serial, &snd_bff, &rcv_bff, &serial_port ]
            ( LPCTSTR test_name, DWORD flags ) {
                if( Serial.InitSerial( serial_port, CBR_9600, flags ) ) {
                    _tprintf( _T("%40s\r\n\r\n"), test_name );
                    srand( 0 );
                    for( int n = 1; n <= MAX_BYTES_SND_RCV; n++ ) {
                        for( int i = 0; i < n; i++ ) snd_bff[ i ] = rand( );
                        if( Serial.write( snd_bff, n ) == -1 ) break;
                        if( Serial.read(  rcv_bff, n ) == -1 ) break;
                        _tprintf( _T("\r\n") );
                    }
                    Serial.CloseSerial( );
                } else {
                    _tprintf( _T("Error: Can't open %s serial port!\r\n"), serial_port );
                }
        };

        SerialTest( _T(    "Normal Serial Communication"), FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL );
        SerialTest( _T("Overlapped Serial Communication"), FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED );
    } else {
        _tprintf( _T("Error: Com port is not specifed!\r\n") );
    }
}
```

You need to start it by setting the com-port ( "COM1" for example ):

```
    >APP COM1
```

Please, Don't criticize my style of writing the program. I tried to be as short as possible. There are no comments, but I believe that those who understand, don't need them.
Please, tell me if it is possible to perform the task with the `SleepEx( )` function at all, without using events, and if so, if possible, give your version of these two methods `cSerial::readAsync( )` and the `cSerial::writeAsync( )`.

Comment: *but apparently the SleepEx( ) function doesn't work, because it also returns instantly* - no. of course `SleepEx` "work" correct. returns instantly mean that I/O is completed and APC inserted to your thread.

Comment: @RbMm: What does this mean ? I think ReadFileEx( ) function should be returned immediately because it is asynchronous, but the other SleepEx( ) function must return control either when ReadFileEx( ) reads some data or when the timeout expires?

Comment: `SleepEx ` return when timeout expires or APC inserted to thread. if you use I/O with APC completion - APC will be inserted when I/O completed. so your I/O completed

Comment: @RbMm: Thank you for the answers, but I can't understand what you're telling me. :( Is there any way to do what I want using SleepEx( ). Can you give me a simple (or complete) example?

Comment: what is unclear ? I/O request is finished. APC inserted to thread, SleepEx return, as must. no any problems with SleepEx

Comment: @RbMm: But look at the print in the console. To read 1 byte, the sequence of ReadFileEx( ) and SleepEx( ) is repeated more than a thousand times, which leads to a 100% load on the used thread. If this is the "solution", it is better to use events or even synchronous operations.

Comment: no, you not understand. again - your I/O completed. what is unclear here ?

Comment: @RbMm: :) For me it is not completed, because Completion callback, reports 0 bytes transferred thousand times for one byte, and at the end it reports 1 and then my function completes.

Comment: not exist "for me". I/O completed - if your callback is called. your ignore status code, which is error. look for `lpOverlapped->Internal`

Comment: This is a Japanese article, but there is also a sample source. [非同期 I/O (3/4) 完了ルーチン](https://www.keicode.com/windows/win05.php), [comproutine.zip](https://www.keicode.com/windows/win05/comproutine.zip) There is a description that it is inconvenient to call SleepEx in the main thread with UI, and both ReadFileEx and SleepEx are called in the worker thread. There may be some such conditions.

Comment: @RbMm: Ok, as I see the use of the SleepEx( ) function does not work for me. It was just interesting to me. Thank you all!

Comment: no, of course it work correct "for you" too. you simply have not enough knowledge. you ignore my question - `lpOverlapped->Internal` - what value have in callback

Comment: @RbMm: `lpOverlapped->Internal` is never set as `STATUS_PENDING` in my Completion callback.

Comment: of course, but are i say that it wil be set to `STATUS_PENDING` ?! i ask which value here

Comment: @RbMm: It is always 0 in my Completion callback.

Comment: i doubt that no errors (`lpOverlapped->Internal == 0`) but and no bytes transfered ( `InternalHigh == 0`). in any case your io is completed

Comment: @Ted  After `SleepEx` which returns before `cbCompletion` returns, you call `ReadFileEx` again.

Comment: @YangXiaoPo: Yes, I keep calling the sequence of ReadFileEx( ) function and SleepEx( ) function, otherwise the data will never come and I go out with timeout.

Comment: @YangXiaoPo-MSFT- *SleepEx which returns before cbCompletion returns,* - absolute false. *cbCompletion* called inside *SleepEx*

Comment: @Ted Try to keep calling `SleepEx` and call the others `ReadFileEx` in `cbCompletion`.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Asynchronous Procedure Calls](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sync/asynchronous-procedure-calls),

> When a user-mode APC is queued, the thread to which it is queued is
> not directed to call the APC function unless it is in an alertable
> state. A thread enters an alertable state when it calls the **SleepEx**,
> SignalObjectAndWait, MsgWaitForMultipleObjectsEx,
> WaitForMultipleObjectsEx, or WaitForSingleObjectEx function.

And these called APCs don't contain `cbCompletion`(Read Action doesn’t complete). That's why `bytes_transfered == 0` and `SleepEx()` return instantly.

I test the modified **Kenny Kerr(Parallel Programming with C++ – Part 1 – Asynchronous Procedure Calls)** code with [Multithreaded Pipe Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/ipc/multithreaded-pipe-server).
**SleepEx function can be used with asynchronous functions without events.**

Modified client Code:

```
#include <windows.h> 
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <assert.h>

void CALLBACK ReadFileCompleted(DWORD errorCode,
    DWORD bytesCopied,
    OVERLAPPED* overlapped);

OVERLAPPED overlapped = { 0 };
HANDLE pipe;
DWORD buffer = 0;
DWORD status = ERROR_SUCCESS;

#define BUFSIZE 512
LPCTSTR lpvMessage = TEXT("Default message from client.");
TCHAR  chBuf[BUFSIZE];
BOOL   fSuccess = FALSE;
DWORD  cbRead, cbToWrite, cbWritten, dwMode;
LPCTSTR lpszPipename = TEXT("\\\\.\\pipe\\mynamedpipe");

VOID
(CALLBACK WriteFileCompleted)(
    _In_    DWORD dwErrorCode,
    _In_    DWORD dwNumberOfBytesTransfered,
    _Inout_ LPOVERLAPPED lpOverlapped
    ) {

}

int main()
{
    // Open the client end of a named pipe.
    pipe = (::CreateFile(lpszPipename,
        //FILE_READ_DATA,
        GENERIC_READ |  // read and write access 
        GENERIC_WRITE,
        0, // no sharing
        0, // default security
        OPEN_EXISTING,
        FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED,
        0)); // no template

    if (INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE == pipe)
    {
        // The pipe is not accessible.
        status = ::GetLastError();
    }
    else
    {
        cbToWrite = (lstrlen(lpvMessage) + 1) * sizeof(TCHAR);
        _tprintf(TEXT("Sending %d byte message: \"%s\"\n"), cbToWrite, lpvMessage);

        fSuccess = WriteFileEx(
            pipe,                  // pipe handle 
            lpvMessage,             // message 
            cbToWrite,              // message length 
            &overlapped,             // bytes written 
            WriteFileCompleted);                  // not overlapped 

        if (!fSuccess)
        {
            _tprintf(TEXT("WriteFile to pipe failed. GLE=%d\n"), GetLastError());
            return -1;
        }

        printf("\nMessage sent to server, receiving reply as follows:\n");
        //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        // Read the first value from the pipe into the buffer asynchronously.
        if (!::ReadFileEx(pipe,
            &buffer,
            sizeof(buffer),
            &overlapped,
            ReadFileCompleted))
        {
            // The server may have closed the pipe or the connection was lost.
            status = ::GetLastError();
        }
        else
        {
            while (ERROR_SUCCESS == status)
            {
                // Wait until one or more APCs are queued.
                const DWORD sleepResult = ::SleepEx(10000, // Suspend indefinitely
                    TRUE); // Alertable

// Since the thread is suspended indefinitely it will only return
// after one or more APCs are called.
                //assert(WAIT_IO_COMPLETION == sleepResult)
                //Edit 1:
                if (sleepResult == WAIT_IO_COMPLETION)
                {
                    _tprintf(TEXT("sleepResult == WAIT_IO_COMPLETION: %d \n"), buffer);
                    //_tprintf(TEXT("\"%d\"\n"), buffer);
                }
                else if (sleepResult == 0)
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return status;
}

void CALLBACK ReadFileCompleted(const DWORD errorCode,
    const DWORD bytesCopied,
    OVERLAPPED* overlapped)
{
    // The read request may have failed asynchronously.
    // The server may have closed the pipe or the connection was lost.
    status = errorCode;

    if (ERROR_SUCCESS == status)
    {
        // The read request completed successfully.
        //assert(sizeof(buffer) == bytesCopied);

        // The current value is available in the buffer.
        //std::cout << buffer << std::endl;
        _tprintf(TEXT("\"%d\"\n"), buffer);

        // Read the next value from the pipe into the buffer asynchronously.
        if (!::ReadFileEx(pipe,
            &buffer,
            sizeof(buffer),
            overlapped,
            ReadFileCompleted))
        {
            // The server may have closed the pipe or the connection was lost.
            status = ::GetLastError();
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Edit 1: 
[image]

Edit 2: 
After Debugging the code, I got that `SleepEx` returns `WAIT_IO_COMPLETION` before `cbCompletion` called. That’s why `!bytes_transfered == true`. The second picture also shows that.

Comment: *And these called APCs don't contain cbCompletion(Read Action doesn’t complete). That's why bytes_transfered == 0 and SleepEx() return instantly.* - this is absolute false

Comment: @RbMm It's my inference. But I cannot reproduce it in my test program.

Comment: *And these called APCs don't contain cbCompletion* ?! based on what yo decide this ? the *cbCompletion* of course called

Comment: Oh, I got it, `SleepEx` return `WAIT_IO_COMPLETION` before `cbCompletion` called. That’s why `!bytes_transfered == true`.

Comment: no, senseless. at first apc callback called before SleepEx return WAIT_IO_COMPLETION. second - at all unclear

Comment: no. Debugging shows `SleepEx` returns before first apc callback called.

Comment: absolute false, this only mean you bad debug